# Display No Record found message inside Bar Chart using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, bar-chart

I want to show text message when there is no data in the bar Chart. I am using `react-chart-js-2` and following code to show the message but it's not working. I don't know what's going wrong but I think this could is working as I am referring this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/x04ptfuu/

```
Chart.plugins.register({
  afterDraw: function(chart) {
    if (chart.data.datasets.length === 0) {
      // No data is present
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      var width = chart.chart.width;
      var height = chart.chart.height
      chart.clear();    
      ctx.save();
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
      ctx.font = "16px normal 'Helvetica Nueue'";
      ctx.fillText('No data to display', width / 2, height / 2);
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
});
```

My Bar Chart canvas element available with react chartjs 2:

```
<Bar data={this.state.chart2Data}
    height={650}
    width={1200}
    options={{
        title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Repetitive Observations - Review 2',
        fontSize: 16,
        fontColor: '#000000'
        },
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'top',
            labels: {
                fontColor: '#000000'
            }

        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
               display: function(context) {
                return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] !== 0},
               color: '#ffffff'
            }
         },
        responsive: false,
        scales: {
            xAxes:[{
              scaleLabel: {
                  display: true,
                  labelString: 'Activity',
                  fontStyle: 'bold',
                  fontColor: '#000000',
                  fontSize: 13
                },
                ticks: {
                    fontColor: '#000000',
                    minRotation: 90
                }
            }],
            yAxes:[{
                ticks: {
                    fontColor: '#000000'
                    }
            }]
        }
    }}  
/>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x04ptfuu/) you are refering is purely on `Javascript`.

In React you have [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html),

```
{this.state.chart2Data && this.state.chart2Data.length > 0 ? <Bar data = {this.state.chart2Data}
    height = {
        650
    }
    width = {
        1200
    }
    options = {
        {
            title:
            {
                display: true,
                text: 'Repetitive Observations - Review 2',
                fontSize: 16,
                fontColor: '#000000'
            },
            legend:
            {
                display: true,
                position: 'top',
                labels:
                {
                    fontColor: '#000000'
                }

            },
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            plugins:
            {
                datalabels:
                {
                    display: function(context)
                    {
                        return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] !== 0
                    },
                    color: '#ffffff'
                }
            },
            responsive: false,
            scales:
            {
                xAxes: [
                {
                    scaleLabel:
                    {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Activity',
                        fontStyle: 'bold',
                        fontColor: '#000000',
                        fontSize: 13
                    },
                    ticks:
                    {
                        fontColor: '#000000',
                        minRotation: 90
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [
                {
                    ticks:
                    {
                        fontColor: '#000000'
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
    />
    :
    <div> No Data to display </div>
}
```

Comment: Even though it works but I want to clear the chart and show the message on chart itself. With conditional approach I won't be able to properly format and show the message inside empty chart

Comment: In that case you need to use some CSS to show text on chart.